# Should a Complete List of International Dialing Codes Be Provided or Only A Subset?

Tags: forms, telephone

I am designing a form which prompts the user for their mobile number. The platform is global and therefore the form should be able to accept any mobile number from any country.

Looking at [this Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_country_calling_codes) which lists all the international dialling codes I see there are some not so familiar entries should as

```
Cocos (Keeling) Islands +61 89162
Turks and Caicos Islands    +1 649
Globalstar (Mobile Satellite Service)   +881 8, +881 9
```

It is not very likely that the users who are going to use this platform will be living in these locations (the last one is not even a country but rather some telecommunication facility). However, this is not certain and some users may need to provide mobile numbers with these dialling codes.

How accommodating should the form be regarding these lesser know international dialling codes? I don't seem them on any forms on the internet I have seen. Is there a standard list that is typically used?

Answer (score 1):

Excellent job designing for all kind of public.

I would use a standard double boxed (Dialing code + Phone), and when the user click in the dialing it will list ALL the dial codes.

[image]

[image]

Link to dialing codes: https://countrycode.org/

Comment: The field design is not the question. I already have that. It's more to do with what should be a standard list of countries to have in the drop down list. That web link to countrycode.org is good source. I will go with that.